# How to propagate a function inside another function?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

almost finished this todoApp:
https://jsfiddle.net/cpbt9dm7/

Everything works good beside the fact that I have a function that removes projects(sidebar from left)

```
function deleteProject(){
    let allRemoveButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-button');
    allRemoveButtons.forEach(function(el){
        el.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log(el.dataset.name);
            projectStorage.splice(el.dataset.name, 1);
            localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(projectStorage));
            location.reload();
        })
    })
}
```

The function works but only once, it basically doesn't propagate for for every project delete button.

If I add only one project I can remove it;
If I add 2 projects I can remove only 1, doesn't matter which one;
If I add more than 2 projects, I can still remove just 1 project.

I call the function inside the function that creates projects:

```
function populateProjects(){
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.classList = "eachproject";
    newDiv.dataset.name = projectStorage[projectStorage.length - 1].dataset;

    let newButton = document.createElement('button');
    newButton.classList = "list-button";
    newButton.dataset.name = projectStorage[projectStorage.length - 1].dataset;
    newButton.innerHTML = projectStorage[projectStorage.length -1].title
    newButton.style.background = projectStorage[projectStorage.length -1].priority;

    let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
    newSpan.innerHTML = projectStorage[projectStorage.length -1].date
    newSpan.style.float = "right"
    let deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
    deleteButton.classList = 'delete-button'
    deleteButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>'
    deleteButton.dataset.name = projectStorage[projectStorage.length - 1].dataset;


    document
    .querySelector(".projects")
    .appendChild(newDiv)
    .appendChild(newButton)
    document
    .querySelector(".projects")
    .appendChild(newDiv)
    .appendChild(newSpan)
    document
    .querySelector('.projects')
    .appendChild(newDiv)
    .appendChild(deleteButton)    


    deleteProject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be your `splice()`. The first parameter is meant to be an integer index into your array (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). You could get the index of the dataset name and then use that in your splice. E.g.

```
var itemIndex = projectStorage.indexOf(el.dataset.name);
projectStorage.splice(itemIndex, 1);
```

Alternatively, you could use a filter to create a new array with the dataset name removed:

```
var newProjectStorage = projectStorage.filter(project => project.dataset !== el.dataset.name);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately el.dataset.name is already a number. // At the beginning of the js file I set let projectCounter = 0 and set it to dataset and increment it with every project created. It comes as a string from HTML though, I'll try to make it an integer tbh.

Comment: It has to do with location.reload(); , basically I added a new line el.closest('div').remove(); and removed reload but now the storage doesnt update but the UI updates, if i let the both lines on , the storage updates but it doesnt work more than once